# Help with Google Marketplace

Tags: google-play-store

How can I contact Google in regards to an issue that I am having with the marketplace? I am trying to buy an application and it is not working. I tried to buy another one and that didn't work, so I need Google's help at this point.

Comment: What is the nature of the problem? trouble arranging payment? authorising payment? downloading apps?

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure that the standard way (that Google want you to go through) to do this is to start by going through the [Android Market Help](http://www.google.com/support/androidmarket/bin/topic.py?topic=15869) (also available by going to the help menu within the Android Market app) going into the Buying Apps section, a lot of sectsions there have Contact Us links that you can fill in with your problem and details.

If that doesn't help you then can search the [Market support forums](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Android+Market).